# C++ working with a map with vectors as values

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary

I have a map that maps strings to vectors of strings:

`std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>>> myMap;`.

Is there a nice way (as little code as possible while still being readable) to append a value to the vector of a given key?

How to handle the case of adding a value to a vector for a new key for which the vector hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: `myMap[key].push_back(value)`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude does the operator[] handle the case when key is not in the map?

Comment: And the `operator[]` function creates a default-constructor or initialized value if the key doesn't exist, so for your vector it will create an empty vector. This should be well-documented in many places.

Comment: This means, on the other hand, that you cannot use `operator[]` if you *don't* want to insert non-existing elements (and you cannot use it on const maps). In such a scenario, you'd rely on `find` function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want:

```
myMap["key"].push_back("string");
```

If the vector for this key doesn't exist, it will be created automatically.

Comment: "Maybe it is worth pointing out an empty vector will be created automatically." -someone's deleted comment